# how to install 'impressionist' plugin manually step by step? (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

This would really help out a lot. I tried to install the plugin through the command and I can't ever seem to get it working correctly. (https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist)
Can someone outline the steps numerically with the specific line of codes that would be used and the file names? #1-10, etc?
I'm trying to track the number of times people click into a user's profile (i.e. localhost:3000/users/1). The # of times a profile is viewed in other words so that I can show it on localhost:3000/users view but that will be the next step.

This is what I have done so far:
1. bundle installed gem 'impressionist'

1. tried to run "rails g impressionist" and "rake db:migrate" but I'm trying to figure out if it worked or not
2. created a controller file named "widgets_controller.rb inside app\controllers\ which has the following code

   WidgetsController < ApplicationController
   impressionist :actions=>[:show,:index]

   end
3. create a model file named widget.rb inside app\models which has the following code

   class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
   is_impressionable
   end
4. added this line inside the app\models\user.rb file

   def show
   @widget = Widget.find
   impressionist(@widget,message:"wtf is a widget?") #message is optional
   end
5. Then I'm using this code line @widget.impressionist_count in my views to try to display the count.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're trying to do. StackOverflow is designed to deal with specific programming problems. Please include information  about what you've tried, what did or didn't work, what code you've written, and what errors you've received.

Comment: I updated the original post. Am I going in the right direction?

Comment: Did I go through the steps correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to follow the tutorial at [impressionist](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist) page.

1 - Add line `gem 'impressionist'` to your gemfile and run `bundle install` command, than run `rails g impressionist` and `rake db:migrate` commands.
2 - In the controller you want to track (in your case users_controller) add

`class UsersController < ApplicationController`

`impressionist :actions => [:show]`

3 - In the model user.rb add

`class User < ActiveRecord::Base`

`is_impressionable`

4 - In users/index.html.erb view add

`<%= @user.impressionist_count %>`